# Overlaying GlSurfaceView with SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

In my application I have `GlSurfaceView` and I also want to have `SlidingPaneLayout`, which when expanded would overlay `GlSurfaceView`. My question is how to do it, so that whenever `GlSurfaceView` is overlayed by `SlidingPaneLayout` it would not rerender overlayed area?

Comment: The GLSurfaceView surface is placed below the View layer, so anything you do with a View will appear on top automatically. Put them both in a FrameLayout so they appear on top of each other.

Comment: I understand that, however when I run debugging tool which displays which parts of the screen have been drawn more than 2 times I get on SlidingPaneLayout that it was drawn twice.

Comment: SurfaceView surfaces are composited by SurfaceFlinger, not the app; since it's composing the entire View layer with the surface's layer, you can't avoid overdraw. Fortunately it will usually be happening in the display hardware via overlays. Out of curiosity, if you disable the SurfaceView, does your debug tool still indicate overdraw?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by disabling view. When I do not initialize GlSurfaceView then debug tool do not show that view has been drawn twice. Even though GlRenderer is set to draw only when dirty and onDrawFrame is not launched, debug tool shows that view has been drawn twice. It also makes scrolling items less smooth. Maybe I should manipulate the height of the GlSurfaceView so that it won't be under SlidingPaneLayout?